# For $ f(n)=(\sqrt{\log n})^{\sqrt{n}}$ ; $ g(n)=(\sqrt{n})^{\log n} $ is $ f(n)=\Theta(g(n)), f(n)=o(g(n)) $ or $ f(n) = \omega(g(n)) $?

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

**Problem**: For $ f(n)=(\sqrt{\log n})^{\sqrt{n}}$  ;  $ g(n)=(\sqrt{n})^{\log n} $ is $ f(n)=\Theta(g(n)), f(n)=o(g(n)) $ or $ f(n) = \omega(g(n)) $?

**Attempt:** I have done many attempts on draft paper but it seemed so complicated as to how I should continue, one thing that I thing must be done is to convert to the form of $ 2^{log} $ in the limits and perhaps use some sort of trick which I don't see. I have some dillemas, I'm not sure if $ f(n) = \omega(g(n)) $ or $ f(n) = o(g(n)) $ but my gut feeling is that the answer is one of the two, in any case I start out as such:
$ \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} =\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^{\log f(n)}}{2^{\log g(n)}}=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^{\frac{\sqrt{n} \cdot \log n}{2}}}{2^{\frac{(\log n)^{2}}{2}}}=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\left(2^{\log n}\right)^{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}}}{\left(2^{\log n}\right)^{\frac{\log n}{2}}} $
I falsely proceeded to  $ \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\log n}=\infty $ and then said  $ f(n) = \omega(g(n)) $ but realized the mistake I've done and I'm now absolutely clueless as to how to proceed.

Can you please help?

Comment: Let's calculate $A = \log(f(n)/g(n))=\frac{\sqrt{n}-\log n}{2}\log n$. $\lim_{n\to\infty} A = \infty$, so $f(n) = \omega(g(n))$

Comment: Me and a few of my friends got really convoluted in the problem and it took us a lot of time to try to reach a conclusive answer. I understand now and thank you very much.